# Why does @change or @input work with custom v-model component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, v-model

Let's say I've created a custom component `Comp.vue` that basically is an wrapped input element with a `model-value` prop and `@update="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)`.

It might look like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
  <label :for="name" class="block relative">
    <div>
        {{ label }}
    </div>
        <input
          :name="name"
          :type="type"
          :value="modelValue"
          @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
        />
  </label>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: {
    label: {
      required: true,
      type: String,
    },
    modelValue: {
      required: false,
      default: "",
      type: [String, Number],
    },
    type: {
      default: "text",
      type: String,
    },
    name: {
      required: false,
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
};
</script>
```

Now I've imported that component in App.vue.

Why does this work:

```
<Comp @change="doSth1()" />
<Comp @input="doSth2()" />
```

My custom `Comp.vue` never emits any of those events.

I've created a custom playground that logs those events:
[Playground Link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `input` and `change` are native DOM events, Vue listens to them automatically.

Please check the Vue docs: [Directives, v-on](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-on) and [HTMLElement, input events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement#input_events)

> When used on a normal element, it listens to [native DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) only. When used on a custom element component, it listens to custom events emitted on that child component.

It looks like Vue still listens to native HTML input events by custom components.

For example, there is also an `beforeinput` event which is also fired automatically and listened by Vue. So you can add a directive for it also.

```
@beforeinput="beforeinputTriggered()"
```

Update to answer [@Thibault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69435810/2487565)

The changing of modelValue themself does not fire 'input/change' events. If we remove the HTML input element in the Comp.vue, then the 'beforeinput/input/change' events will be not fired.

Here is the proof: [same component with a +1 button](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) fires only the `@update:modelValue` event.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you're basicly passing modelValue as a prop. And I believe that when the value of modelValue changes it triggers an input or change event.

Comment: No, it is wrong. The changing of modelValue themself does not fire `input` & `change` events.

Comment: @Tolbxela yeah I thought about Vue listening to native input events too but wasn't sure. Thanks for clarifying!